# Simple rewrite rule doesnt work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, clean-urls

I need to clean this url:

```
localhost/film/film/?n=zatvorenici
```

to be like this:

```
localhost/film/film/zatvorenici/
```

and my code doesnt work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^film/([a-z-]+)/$ /film/?n=$1
```

Comment: where is your htaccess file located?

Comment: In rooot folder

Comment: put this in film folder

Comment: Still doesnt work...

Comment: to which file you are redirecting like `film/?n=$1` film have some extension or not?

Comment: i have index.php file inside of film folder (there i pick up $_GET and list movie based on get var)

Comment: Is the word `film` literal? Or, is it like `<anyfilm>`? And you have 2 subdirectories called `film`?

Comment: i have beacuse it is on local and the first "film" is folder of fhoce website (in htdoc folder). and this film part is static it is always film but "?n=zatvorenici" changes on click

Comment: ...and you've already changed the URLs in your application to `localhost/film/film/zatvorenici/` - that is the URL you are linking to?

Comment: You mean links in my .php? no, links are leading to something like this film/?n=zatvorenici because i need get var, but i want to clean that url now

Comment: Well, that would seem to be the important first step you are missing. You need to change the links in your application, so that they point to the canonical "pretty" URL, eg. `href="/film/film/zatvorenici/"` (which, incidentally, is what the `RewriteRule` above is looking for. So, unless you change the URL, this is never going to match). The rule in .htaccess then _internally rewrites_ the request to the actual file that handles the request. eg. `/film/film/index.php?u=zatvorenici`.

Comment: you dont understand, this parametar value, in this case "zatvorenici" is criteria for finding movie and listing from database. if i put clean link in href like film/zatvorenici/, this page wont work and i wouldnt be able to get movie info. and there is no "/zatvorenici/" folder, that is dynamic parameter from database... i havent made this work yet, but thank you for your effort i appriciate it

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^film/([a-z-]+)/$ index?n=$1 [L]
```

put this in film directory.

Comment: please edit what variable you are getting inside index.php and other details if missed.

Comment: which language are you using if php then it will be `index.php` or any other language please use above as per your need.

Comment: if (isset($_GET['n'])) {
 $title = $_GET['n'];
 $novifilm = $string_with_dashes = str_replace('-',' ',$title);
 //echo $novifilm;
} i get var like this (index.php in film folder)

Comment: If this `.htaccess` is in the _first_ `film` directory, then you will still need a `RewriteBase /film/film` (or something) to rewrite to the _second_ `film` subdirectory.

Comment: put .htaccess in first film directory for the above.